# Where to Start: .Net(Xamarin) map viewer with cached map and overlay ability

Tags: .net, development

I am new to the whole GIS topic. Two days ago, I was asked to develop a map viewer.

I know that

- it should be a Xamarin Application
- it should display a local cached map (a vector map)
- I should be able to draw shapes on it at specific coordinates

The last two days I browsed the Internet to find some info on where to start. I found this Stackexchange, and many other free and licensed developer kits. I think openlayers would suffice my needs, but it's mainly for web applications which is a viable option, if I cannot find something good for .Net.

I found ArcObjects but it is not free and I am not sure if this is what I am looking for. It seems that it is used mainly for ArcGIS Plugins.

Also I found Mapbox SDK, but it only supports iOS and Android.

Has anyone experience with [dotspatial](https://dotspatial.codeplex.com/)?

I hope you guys can point me to the right SDK for my needs.

Edit:

An SDK was not the right thing. I am looking for a good GIS Framework. For displaying maps and drawing shapes onto it.